# How to get $P(A\mid B, C)$ from $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\mid C)$, $P(B,C)$

Tags: probability

Building on [this old question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/how-can-i-calculate-the-conditional-probability-of-several-events), I have $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\mid C)$, $P(B,C)$ and need to calculate $P(A\mid B,C)$

I am stuck with the obv relationships, which include:

$$
\begin{align}
    P(A\mid B,C)  &= P(A,B,C) / P(B,C)\\
    P(A\mid B)    &= P(A,B) / P(B)\\
    P(A\mid C)    &= P(A,C) / P(C)\\
\end{align}
$$

What relationship links $P(A,B,C)$ with $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\mid C)$, $P(B,C)$? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have enough information.

Suppose there are six equally probable alternatives $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Take $A=\{1,2,6\}$, $B=\{2,3,4\}$, $C=\{1,3,5\}$. Then $p(A\mid B)=p(A\mid C) = \frac{1}{3},p(B\cap C)=\frac{1}{6}$, and $p(A\mid B\cap C)=0$.

If we take $A=\{1,2\},B=\{2,3,4\},C=\{2,5,6\}$, then $p(A\mid B)=p(A\mid C)=\frac{1}{3},p(B\cap C)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $p(A\mid B\cap C)=1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!