# What does suffice to calculate $P(C\mid A,B)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In [How to get $P(A\mid B, C)$ from $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\mid C)$, $P(B,C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820676/269050) it is shown that there isn't enough information to compute $P(A\mid BC)$ from $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\mid C)$ and $P(B\mid C)$.

**My question:** what other information should we provide?

---

**Motivation**

Consider the associated Bernoulli distributions $B_A$, $B_B$ and $B_C$ (meaning the B.D. with parameters $P(A)$, etc.)

It is easy to see that the (Pearson) correlation coefficient $\rho_{B_A,B_B}$ conveys the same information that $P(A|B)$ (you can compute one from the other). This fact can be used in software to produce a sample of $B$ conditional to a sample of $A$ by generating two samples $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ and $b_1,\cdots,b_n$ appropriately correlated.

So, my question could be rephrased as: Is it possible to compute $\rho_{B_A,B_{BC}}$ from $\rho_{B_A,B_B}$, $\rho_{B_A,B_C}$ and $\rho_{B_B,B_C}$ assuming you also know $B_A$, $B_B$ and $B_C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is easy to see that the (Pearson) correlation coefficient $\rho_{B_A,B_B}$ conveys the same information that $P(A\mid B)$ (you can compute one from the other).

Actually I don't see this, unless you are implicitly assuming that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are known when you write that $B_A$ and $B_B$ are Bernoulli distributions with parameters $P(A)$ and $P(B).$

The question [How to get $P(A\mid B, C)$ from $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\mid C)$, $P(B,C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820676/how-to-get-pa-mid-b-c-from-pa-mid-b-pa-mid-c-pb-c)
did not assume $P(A),$ $P(B),$ and $P(C)$ were known, and neither did the answer. I think you are looking for an answer that assumes those probabilities are known.

So let's suppose you know not just
$P(A\mid B),$ $P(A\mid C),$ and $P(B\mid C),$
but also $P(A),$ $P(B),$ and $P(C),$
and that each of the probabilities $P(A),$ $P(B),$ and $P(C)$ is non-zero.
Equivalently, we can say you know $P(A),$ $P(B),$ $P(C),$
$P(A\cap B),$ $P(A\cap C),$ and $P(B\cap C),$
since you can compute the first six probabilities from these last six
probabilities and vice versa.

Now let's define a few symbols for convenience:
\begin{align}
p &= P(A \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement), \\
q &= P(A^\complement \cap B \cap C^\complement), \\
r &= P(A^\complement \cap B^\complement \cap C), \\
s &= P(A \cap B \cap C^\complement), \\
t &= P(A \cap B^\complement \cap C), \\
u &= P(A^\complement \cap B \cap C), \\
v &= P(A \cap B \cap C).
\end{align}

Then what we know is
\begin{align}
p + s + t + v &= P(A), \\
q + s + u + v &= P(B), \\
r + t + u + v &= P(C), \\
s + v &= P(A\cap B), \\
t + v &= P(A\cap C), \\
u + v &= P(B\cap C).
\end{align}

We have only six equations for seven unknowns.
We also have some constraints: $p \geq 0,$ $q \geq 0,$ $r \geq 0,$
$s \geq 0,$ $t \geq 0,$ $u \geq 0,$ $v \geq 0,$ and
$p + q + r + s + t + u + v \leq 1,$
but that's still not enough to determine a unique solution in general.

What this means is that in the general case, you don't know
$P(A \cap B \cap C)$; at best you can find a minimum and maximum possible value.
But if it were possible to deduce any of the various three-variable
conditional probabilities such as $P(A\mid B \cap C),$
then from the known probabilities you could also compute 
$P(A \cap B \cap C)$ exactly.

As an example, suppose the probability space contains eight equally probable,
disjoint events $a, b, c, d, e, f, g,$ and $h,$ and consider the events
\begin{align}
A &= \{a, d, e\}, \\
B &= \{b, d, f\}, \\
C &= \{c, e, f\}, \\
A' &= \{a, d, g\}, \\
B' &= \{b, e, g\}, \\
C' &= \{c, f, g\}.
\end{align}
Then $P(A) = P(A') = P(B) = P(B') = P(C) = P(C') = \frac38$ and
$P(A\cap B) = P(A'\cap B') = P(A\cap C) = P(A'\cap C') 
= P(B\cap C) = P(B'\cap C') = \frac18,$
but $P(A\mid B \cap C) = 0$ while $P(A'\mid B' \cap C') = 1.$

In conclusion, even if you know all of the probabilities
$P(A),$ $P(B),$ $P(C),$
$P(A\cap B),$ $P(A\cap C),$ $P(B\cap C),$
$P(A\mid B),$ $P(B\mid A),$ $P(A\mid C),$ $P(C\mid A),$ 
$P(C\mid B),$ and $P(B\mid C),$
in the general case you still do not have enough information to determine other probabilities such as $P(A\mid B \cap C)$ or $P(A\cap B \mid C).$

Comment: Thanks a lot. My apologies for not being more explicit about the hypothesis (i.e., what was known, what wasn't), which you accurately deduced. Interestingly enough, I learn in the last few hours that there are 4x4 linear equation systems that capture the same information and they have rank 3. Many thanks for the (counter-) example too.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\mathsf P(B\mid C)$ and $\mathsf P(A\mid C)$ so shall require either $\mathsf P(A,B\mid C)$ or $\mathsf P(B\mid A,C)$.

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B,C)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B,C)}{\mathsf P(B,C)}=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A, B\mid C)}{\mathsf P(B\mid C)} =\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid C)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A,C)}{\mathsf P(B\mid C)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, isn't it possible to deduce $P(A|B,C)$ from "simple" probabilities like $P(A)$, $P(A|B)$, etc.? In my case I don't have information about $P(A,B|C)$, etc.